# CSS cannot cut image by pixels correctly [Sprite Box]?

Tags: html, css

I tried following the math for the previous cut images and put my own image on there but it just shows up as a blank can you tell me where the problem is?

```css
#paymentForm {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #f9f9f7;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  
  height: auto;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  margin-top:30px;
  width: 287px;
}
#paymentForm span{color: #555555; font-size: 11px}

#paymentForm li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

#paymentForm label {
  color: #555;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
#paymentForm input[type=text]{
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  width: 275px;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
}
#paymentForm input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #ddd;
}
#paymentForm input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #ddd;
  opacity: 1;
}
#paymentForm input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #ddd;
  opacity: 1;
}
#paymentForm input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #ddd;
}
#paymentForm input:focus {
  outline: 1px solid #3388dd;
}
    #paymentForm #card_number {
        background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGINL.png), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGINL.png);
        background-position: 2px -121px, 260px -61px;
        background-size: 120px 361px, 120px 361px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding-left: 54px;
        width: 225px;
        height: 20px;
    }
    #paymentForm #card_number.visa {
        background-position: 2px -163px, 260px -61px
    }
    #paymentForm #card_number.visa_electron {
        background-position: 2px -205px, 260px -61px
    }
    #paymentForm #card_number.mastercard {
        background-position: 2px -247px, 260px -61px
    }
    #paymentForm #card_number.maestro {
        background-position: 2px -289px, 260px -61px
    }
    #paymentForm #card_number.discover {
        background-position: 2px -331px, 260px -61px
    }
    #paymentForm #card_number.valid.visa {
        background-position: 2px -163px, 260px -87px
    }
    #paymentForm #card_number.valid.visa_electron {
        background-position: 2px -205px, 260px -87px
    }
    #paymentForm #card_number.valid.mastercard {
        background-position: 2px -247px, 260px -87px
    }
    #paymentForm #card_number.valid.maestro {
        background-position: 2px -289px, 260px -87px
    }
    #paymentForm #card_number.valid.discover {
        background-position: 2px -331px, 260px -87px
    }

    #paymentForm #card_number.amex {
      background-position: 2px -373px, 260px -61px;
    }
    #paymentForm #card_number.valid.amex {
      background-position: 2px -373px, 260px -87px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="paymentForm">
  
  <input type="text" name="card_number" id="card_number" class="valid visa"  maxlength="20" placeholder="1234 5678 9012 3456">
</div>
```

I decided to add my own with these lines right here

```
#paymentForm #card_number.amex {
  background-position: 2px -373px, 260px -61px;
}
#paymentForm #card_number.valid.amex {
  background-position: 2px -373px, 260px -87px;
}
```

I don't understand these values

```
padding-left: 54px;
width: 225px
```

must I alter these values too?

Here is the image I added the last card American Express but it shows up as a blank white image.
[image: Here is the image]

Comment: You just have the wrong `background-position` value. Try a smaller value. And try to avoid sprites - mainly avoid self-built sprites without any automated build process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the way input is rendered, the two values in question are doing the following:

`padding-left: 54px;` makes sure the text input doesn't overlap the background image of credit card type.

With padding:

[image]

Without padding:

[image]

`width: 225px;` is set specifically because the validation checkmark image is being set at a specific value as well. This isn't necessary and could be made responsive, but, in this case everything is set in precise pixel values.

The proper positioning for amex was:

```
#paymentForm #card_number.amex {
  background-position: 2px -338px, 260px -61px;
}
#paymentForm #card_number.valid.amex {
  background-position: 2px -338px, 260px -87px;
}
```

One of the easiest ways to debug and tweak these is to open developer tools, place the cursor on one of those pixel values and press `up` or `down` arrows on the keyboard. You'll literally see the background image move and be able to fine tune the values.

http://g.recordit.co/8mYkxkPlhl.gif

```css
    #paymentForm #card_number {
        background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGINL.png), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGINL.png);
        background-position: 2px -121px, 260px -61px;
        background-size: 120px 361px, 120px 361px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding-left: 54px;
        width: 225px;
        height: 20px;
    }
    #paymentForm #card_number.visa {
        background-position: 2px -163px, 260px -61px
    }
    #paymentForm #card_number.visa_electron {
        background-position: 2px -205px, 260px -61px
    }
    #paymentForm #card_number.mastercard {
        background-position: 2px -247px, 260px -61px
    }
    #paymentForm #card_number.maestro {
        background-position: 2px -289px, 260px -61px
    }
    #paymentForm #card_number.discover {
        background-position: 2px -331px, 260px -61px
    }
    #paymentForm #card_number.valid.visa {
        background-position: 2px -163px, 260px -87px
    }
    #paymentForm #card_number.valid.visa_electron {
        background-position: 2px -205px, 260px -87px
    }
    #paymentForm #card_number.valid.mastercard {
        background-position: 2px -247px, 260px -87px
    }
    #paymentForm #card_number.valid.maestro {
        background-position: 2px -289px, 260px -87px
    }
    #paymentForm #card_number.valid.discover {
        background-position: 2px -331px, 260px -87px
    }

    #paymentForm #card_number.amex {
      background-position: 2px -338px, 260px -61px;
    }
    #paymentForm #card_number.valid.amex {
      background-position: 2px -338px, 260px -87px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="paymentForm">
  
  <input type="number" id="card_number" class="valid amex" />
  
</div>
```

Comment: I understand but why is the gap so big I calculated math by subtracting 1 value from the previous value and i always got 42 for all like `-331px - -289px` etc.. always 42.. so i added 42 to last one discover should be over -331 but only -338? strange how math changes? i was thinking maybe i forgot to include somewhere where image height gets bigger or something

Comment: The image is also scaled; it's not true pixel to pixel value at this point. Note background-size rule specifically, it's changing the scale of background and that does affect all of your math.

Comment: thanks i dont think other values are scaled math always `42` offset but i understand its different now.. I'll accept this as the answer thanks for the trick with console mode.